# Tabularx how to have continuous text and not page break?

Tags: tables, tabularx

How can I make the text in my table continue on a new page instead of tabularx page breaking because the next row does not fit on the previous page (resulting in unnecessary whitespace)? So essentially I want the third row to go on page 1 and continue on page 2 (with text of row 3 breaking somewhere a few mm's above the first page and continuing a few mm's under the 2nd page)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1 in]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, ltablex, makecell}
\keepXColumns
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\setcellgapes{5pt}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}



    \begin{landscape}
        \tiny
        \makegapedcells
        \setlength\tabcolsep{5pt}
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}>{\bfseries}*{6}{L}@{}}
            \caption{A wide table}\\
            \toprule
            \thead{1}   & \thead{2} & \thead{3} & \thead{4} & \thead{5} & \thead{6}\\
            \midrule
            \lipsum[100]&\lipsum[100]&\lipsum[100]& \lipsum[100]& \lipsum[100]& \lipsum[100]\\
            \lipsum[100]&\lipsum[100]&\lipsum[100]& \lipsum[100]& \lipsum[100]& \lipsum[100]\\
            \lipsum[100]&\lipsum[100]&\lipsum[100]& \lipsum[100]& \lipsum[100]& \lipsum[100]\\
            \lipsum[100]&\lipsum[100]&\lipsum[100]& \lipsum[100]& \lipsum[100]& \lipsum[100]\\
            \bottomrule
%           \endfirsthead

        \end{tabularx}
    \end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as I know, you can break tables only between rows.

Comment: The first to be considered is what is the best format for this huge amount of text . I  do not think that in this case a table would be clear that a list, for instance.